# How to use for loop and set.seed(i) to provide a simulation for rmarkovchain?

Tags: r

I want to perform 1000 simulations for 1 period Markov chain using rmarkov chain function in R.

I have tried combining `set.seed()` function and for loop:

```
for(i in 1:1000){
   set.seed(i) (rmarkovchain(n=1,object=claims,t0="level -2"))
}
```

in order to perform the rmarkovchain function 1000 times to generate 1000 random outputs

```
for(i in 1:1000){set.seed(i) (rmarkovchain(n=1,object=claims,t0="level -2"))}
```

**but R told me Error**

> unexpected symbol in "for(i in 1:1000){set.seed(i) rmarkovchain"

Comment: Try line break after `set.seed(i)`...

Comment: Don't combine `set.seed` and `for` loop. To set the RNG seed is meant to have reproducible results. If you set it just once you will have reproducible results, there is no need to keep resetting it.

Comment: In addition: don't use a loop, just set `n = 1000`. As it is, you're not getting Markov chain samples at all, since they are all just an independent first draw.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use replicate which may help. 
For example:

```
B <- 1000
N <- 1
set.seed(1)

sim.msm <- replicate(B, {
   X <- rmarkovchain(n = N, 
                    object = claims, 
                    t0 = "level -2",
                    include.t0 = TRUE,
                    parallel = TRUE, # set true to parallelize
                    num.cores=detectCores()-1)}) # set your cores
```

Hope it helps (I didn't run it but have used this approach in the past).